# Probability of the sum of independent standard normal random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

Let $X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4$ be independent standard normal random variables and 
$$Y = X_1^2 + X_2^2 + X_3^2 + X_4^2$$ Find the probability that $Y \leq 3$.

For this problem I know that the distribution is $N(0,1)$ for each $X$. I tried combining them to equal $Y$ by finding the distribution of $Y = N(0^2 + 0^2 + 0^2 + 0^2, 1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2) = N(0,4)$. I then tried calculating $P(Z> (0-\mu)/\sigma)$ where $\mu$ is the mean and $\sigma$ is the variance, but obtained $0$ which I know is incorrect. I was then unsure of where to go with this or if my initial strategy was even correct.

Comment: Check my answer to this post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1835684/compute-p1x2y22-when-x-y-is-i-i-d-standard-normal

Answer (score 3):

The distribution of $Y$ cannot be $N(0,4)$ for the simple reason that $Y$ is never negative, while $N(0,4)$ is negative half the time.

The sum of squares of independent random variables is described by the [$\chi^2$ distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution).