# Compute $\mathbb{P}(1<X^2+Y^2<2)$ when $(X,Y)$ is i.i.d. standard normal

Tags: probability, integration, normal-distribution, error-function

> Assume that  $(X,Y)$ is i.i.d. standard normal. Compute $\mathbb{P}(1<X^2+Y^2<2)$.

So I've decided to use polar coordinates to solve and I've gotten to this point:

$$\iint_{1\lt X^2+Y^2\lt2} e^{\frac{-(x^2+y^2)}{2}}dxdy=\iint_{1\lt r^2\lt2}e^{\frac{-r^2}{2}}drd\theta$$

Where  $1\lt r\lt\sqrt2$ and $0\lt \theta \lt 2\pi$.

How do I go about integrating dr? I know I need to use the $\Phi$ function but I'm not so sure how to go about doing that. Any help would be muchappreciated.

Comment: Alternative: $X^2\overset d= Y^2\sim\text{Gamma}(1/2,1/2)$. The sum of two independent gammas is again gamma. It's cdf is well known.

Comment: You cannot integrate it in closed form, you can express it using the erf function. But in this case you forgot the jacobian of the integral, if you include it you find a closed form pretty easily

Comment: @probablyme is there a name of this technique/law?

Comment: You can derive that using the your usual techniques. However, at some point it's just a "common fact", I guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your forgot the Jacobian factor $r$. If you include it, the integral becomes a lot easier to evaluate.

Comment: Oh right how could I forget!!! It seems my calculus knowledge disappears when approaching probability questions. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: He also forgot the normalization constants for the densities:$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2/2}\,dx \neq 1.$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio This is unclear, maybe the OP just focussed on the problematic part.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on @probablyme 's comment, you can use the characteristic function to derive the "common fact".

We have that if $X \sim N(0,1)$, then the characteristic function (CF) of $X^2$ (for any $t \in \mathbb{R}$) is 
$$
\begin{align}
\varphi_{X^2}(t)&=E \left(e^{itX^2} \right) \\ \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{itx^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} dx \\ \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2 \left(1-2it\right)2^{-1}} dx \\ \\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{\left(1-2it\right)2^{-1}}} \, , \quad \mbox{see Gaussian integral on Wikipedia for this result} \\ \\
&= (1-2it)^{-1/2} \quad \mbox{which is the CF of a } \chi^2_{(1)}
\end{align}
$$

Let $Z$ be a r.v. distributed as $\chi^2_{(1)}$. By the Uniqueness Theorem, if $\varphi_{X^2}(t) = \varphi_{Z}(t)$, then $X^2 \sim Z$. So, $X^2 \sim \chi^2_{(1)}$. The same is valid for $Y^2$.

Now, since $X^2, Y^2 \stackrel{iid}{\sim} \chi^2_{(1)}$, we can calculate the CF of $X^2+Y^2$ for any $t \in \mathbb{R}$:

$$
\begin{align}
\varphi_{X^2+Y^2}(t) &= E \left(e^{it(X^2+Y^2)}\right) \\
&= E \left(e^{itX^2}e^{itY^2}\right) \\
&= E \left(e^{itX^2} \right) E\left(e^{itY^2}\right) \, , \quad \mbox{by independence} \\
&= \varphi_{X^2}(t) \varphi_{Y^2}(t) \\
&= (1-2it)^{-1/2} (1-2it)^{-1/2} \\
&= (1-2it)^{-2/2} \, , \quad \mbox{which is the CF of a } \chi^2_{(2)}
\end{align}
$$

Therefore, $X^2+Y^2 \sim \chi^2_{(2)}$, and you can use its PDF to get your answer.

Also, we have that $\chi^2_{(1)}$ is a special case of Gamma ($Gamma(1/2,1/2)$, as stated by @probablyme). The same way,  $\chi^2_{(2)}$ can be seen as $Gamma(2/2,1/2) = Gamma(1,1/2)$ or $Exponential(1/2)$ (another special case of Gamma).

Answer (score 1):

Since $X,Y\sim N(0,1)$ then $X^2,Y^2\sim \chi^2(1)\implies X^2+Y^2\sim \chi^2(2)$ Now use the$\chi^2$ distribution's CDF or PDF as required..

Comment: How did you get that $X^2 \sim Cauchy(1)$?

Comment: This is odd, Cauchy(1) and Cauchy(2) random variables are positive or negative with equal probability while X^2 and X^2+Y^2 are always positive... (Add some suitable expression of bewilderment at the upvote.)

Comment: @Did  : It was a serious typo on my part. I am extremely sorry. I dont know what made me type that.. Please forgive me.

Comment: @Gus_est : It was a serious typo on my part. I am extremely sorry. I dont know what made me type that.. Please forgive me.

Comment: No worries. It happens to us all